# Input placeholder for iPhone 6

Tags: ios, css, iphone, media-queries

How can I format input text placeholder for iPhone 6.

Am using placeholder and formatting it in CSS with Media Queries, but the text doesn't appear correctly. The iPhone 6 shows just few pixels of the text and the rest isn't visible.

Code:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-width: 667px) and (orientation : portrait) {
    .red-fnm placeholder-shown, 
    .red-lnm placeholder-shown, 
    .red-fnm placeholder-shown, 
    .red-mail placeholder-shown {
        display:block;
        font-family:"CamphorStd-Regular", arial, helvetica, sans-serif; color:#e24e36 !important; font-size:24px;
        font-weight: normal;
        background-color:#fcedeb;
        margin-top:-20px;
        paddind-top:-10px;
    }
}
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

```css
.wpcf7-form [class*="comment-form"] input::-webkit-input-placeholder { font-weight: 400; }
.wpcf7-form [class*="comment-form"] input:-moz-placeholder { font-weight: 400; }
.wpcf7-form [class*="comment-form"] input::-moz-placeholder { font-weight: 400; }
.wpcf7-form [class*="comment-form"] input:-ms-input-placeholder { font-weight: 400; }
.wpcf7-form [class*="comment-form"] input:input-placeholder { font-weight: 400; }

.form-group input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder { color:transparent; }
.form-group input:focus:-moz-placeholder { color:transparent; } /* FF 4-18 */
.form-group input:focus::-moz-placeholder { color:transparent; } /* FF 19+ */
.form-group input:focus:-ms-input-placeholder { color:transparent; } /* IE 10+ */
.form-group input:focus:input-placeholder { color:transparent; } /* IE 10+ */

.comment-form-author input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder { color:transparent; }
.comment-form-author input:focus:-moz-placeholder { color:transparent; } /* FF 4-18 */
.comment-form-author input:focus::-moz-placeholder { color:transparent; } /* FF 19+ */
.comment-form-author input:focus:-ms-input-placeholder { color:transparent; } /* IE 10+ */
.comment-form-author input:focus:input-placeholder { color:transparent; } /* IE 10+ */

.comment-form-email input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder { color:transparent; }
.comment-form-email input:focus:-moz-placeholder { color:transparent; } /* FF 4-18 */
.comment-form-email input:focus::-moz-placeholder { color:transparent; } /* FF 19+ */
.comment-form-email input:focus:-ms-input-placeholder { color:transparent; } /* IE 10+ */
.comment-form-email input:focus:input-placeholder { color:transparent; } /* IE 10+ */

.comment-form-url input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder { color:transparent; }
.comment-form-url input:focus:-moz-placeholder { color:transparent; } /* FF 4-18 */
.comment-form-url input:focus::-moz-placeholder { color:transparent; } /* FF 19+ */
.comment-form-url input:focus:-ms-input-placeholder { color:transparent; } /* IE 10+ */
.comment-form-url input:focus:input-placeholder { color:transparent; } /* IE 10+ */

.comment-form-comment input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder { color:transparent; }
.comment-form-comment input:focus:-moz-placeholder { color:transparent; } /* FF 4-18 */
.comment-form-comment input:focus::-moz-placeholder { color:transparent; } /* FF 19+ */
.comment-form-comment input:focus:-ms-input-placeholder { color:transparent; } /* IE 10+ */
.comment-form-comment input:focus:input-placeholder { color:transparent; } /* IE 10+ */

.wpcf7-form textarea:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder { color:transparent; }
.wpcf7-form textarea:focus:-moz-placeholder { color:transparent; } /* FF 4-18 */
.wpcf7-form textarea:focus::-moz-placeholder { color:transparent; } /* FF 19+ */
.wpcf7-form textarea:focus:-ms-input-placeholder { color:transparent; } /* IE 10+ */
.wpcf7-form textarea:focus:input-placeholder { color:transparent; } /* IE 10+ */
```

It is all!

Comment: Thanks. I need in a way a short explanation.. should these be used within the media Query for iPhone 6? 

And focus is when the cursor is in the input field, but am not formatting the field by focus. Thanks!